# Adding subscripts and symbols to facet_wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to create a 2x2 facet plot of some weather conditions over time, and am having trouble adding a degrees symbol and a superscript to some of the facet titles.

```
weatherPLOT = data.frame(weather = rep(c("Soil Temperature (C)", 
                                        "Snow Depth (m)", 
                                        "Air Temperature (C)", 
                                        "Discharge (m3/sec)"), each = 366),
                           day = 1:366,
                           mean = 3, # Obvious place holders,
                           Lo95 = 2, # Are actual numbers in real code
                           Hi95 = 4)

ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = day), data = weatherPLOT) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lo95, ymax = Hi95), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_path(size = 1) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + xlab("Julian Day") +
  facet_wrap( ~ weather, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, scales = "free")
```

I know the trick is to use labeller inside of facet_wrap, but I can't to make it work - I'm just looking to add a degree symbol before the (C) and make the 3 in (m3/sec) superscripted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this to change the text values themselves to appropriate symbols and use the *ggtext* package for the formatting.

`\u00b0` is the Unicode value for the degree sign. `<sup>3</sup>` is the ggtext Markdown code for superscript 3. You specify that theme text should be markdown by using `ggtext::element_markdown()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
weatherPLOT = data.frame(weather = rep(c("Soil Temperature (\u00b0C)", 
                                         "Snow Depth (m)", 
                                         "Air Temperature (\u00b0C)", 
                                         "Discharge (m<sup>3</sup>/sec)"), each = 366),
                         day = 1:366,
                         mean = 3, # Obvious place holders,
                         Lo95 = 2, # Are actual numbers in real code
                         Hi95 = 4)

ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = day), data = weatherPLOT) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lo95, ymax = Hi95), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_path(size = 1) + 
  labs(y = "", x = "Julian Day") +
  theme(strip.text = ggtext::element_markdown()) +
  facet_wrap( ~ weather, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: That's what I tried originally, but just couldn't get the formatting to work - thanks for the quick fix :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be the following:

```
weatherPLOT %>%
  mutate(weather = factor(weather,
                          labels = c(bquote('Air Temperature'*degree*C),
                                     "Discharge~(m^{3}/sec)",
                                     "Snow~Depth~(m)",
                                     bquote('Soil Temperature'*degree*C)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = mean, x = day)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lo95, ymax = Hi95), alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_path(size = 1) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) + xlab("Julian Day") +
  facet_wrap( ~ weather, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, scales = "free", labeller =  label_parsed)
```

[image]